# Expand Dropdown list after it focused

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a data entry ASP.net form and as the user tabs into a Dropdownlist I want the dropdownlist control to expand without having to click on it. The user can then use the arrow keys and select an item and then tab out and the dropdown can revert to its default view. Is there a way to implement this? I tried using the Dropdown extender on a textbox but it just doesnt work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function on `onfocus` event of drop down.

```
function expand() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('ddl');
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

considering your html

```
<select id="ddl" onfocus="expand()">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">AAAA</option>
<option value="2">BBBBB</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zxwojdv/)

Comment: @rwaykos and Imad, I tried this solution. but it doesn't open the dropdown. Even the Fiddle also not opening the dropdown on focus. I tried with Chrome and IE. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a drop down list called 'ddlTest', so try this:

```
 <script>
    function Open() {
       var myDropDown = document.getElementById("ddlTest");
       var length = myDropDown.options.length;           
       myDropDown.size = length;  
   }
   function Select(){
       var myDropDown = document.getElementById("ddlTest");
       myDropDown.size = 1;
       var str = myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].value;
       alert(str);
   }
</script>

<select ID="ddlTest" onfocus="Open()" onfocusout="Select()">
<option>option #1</option>
<option>option #2</option>
<option>option #3</option>
<option>option #4</option>
<option>option #5</option>
<option>option #6</option>
<option>option #7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mate, your code won't let select element by pressing Tab

Comment: It will not shring drop down after selection mate :D

Comment: @Anonymous sorry I am not so good at English, 'Shring' , you mean that you need to get the selected item?

Comment: Sorry, typo error, its shrink, means it is not closing expanded drop down.

Comment: @Anonymous I have updated my answer, so onfocusout it will be collapse the drop down list and will show the selected item. There was a typing error in my code, that I resolved it. You can try it now